# Can't resolve all parameters for createRouterScroller (Angular routing)

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I am new to Angular routing and injected the package to my Ionic project from

```
npm i @angular/router
```

but getting few errors once I injected my appRoutes to app.modules.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { enableTracing: true }   // <-- debugging purposes only
),
```

And here is my app routes

```
 export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: DocumentPage },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: SchedulePage },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: MessagePage,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: WebsitePage }
];
```

errors as

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for createRouterScroller: ([object Object], ?, [object Object]).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15706)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getFactoryMetadata (compiler.js:15558)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15889)
at compiler.js:15792
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15752)
at compiler.js:15224
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15215)
```

Comment: is `createRouterScroller` is your component or class?

Comment: it is nothing being referred too. I dont where my Ionic 4 project is picking it

Comment: `createRouterScroller` Is it your code or angular? Because the issue is with the constructor of that class, it needs a service or something which doesn't provided (see the shape of the constructor as well)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my Angular 5 to Angular 7 and typscript@latest and appscript to 3.2.3, it worked.  Although have to create a new project to get Angular-Routing recognized by the project.